# Compresión .zip, directorios extras

Tags: java

Tengo un problema al comprimir los ficheros en un archivo `.zip`.
Los ficheros se introducen dentro del `.zip` con sus datos perfectamente, pero también se introducen las carpetas de donde estaban estos (`src` y `ficheros`), como indico que no se introduzcan estas carpetas, que únicamente se introduzcan en la raíz del archivo `.zip`.

Este es mi código:

```
package ficheros;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public final class Comprimir {

// PROPIEDADES

private static ZipOutputStream zos = null;
private static ZipEntry ze = null;

// MÉTODOS

public static void ficheros(final String[] ficheros, final String nombreZip) throws IOException {

    // PREPARACIÓN DEL FICHERO ZIP.

    zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(nombreZip)));

    // INSERCIÓN DE LOS FICHEROS AL FICHERO ZIP.

    for (int i = 0; i < ficheros.length; i++) {
        // INTRODUCIMOS EL FICHERO VACÍO CON SU NOMBRE Y EXTENSIÓN.
        ze = new ZipEntry(ficheros[i]);
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
        // INTRODUCIMOS LOS DATOS DEL FICHERO VACIÓ INTRODUCIDO.
        byte[] readAllBytesOfFile = Files.readAllBytes(new File(ficheros[i]).toPath());
        zos.write(readAllBytesOfFile, 0, readAllBytesOfFile.length);
    }

    // CERRAMOS LOS FLUJOS DE DATOS.
    zos.closeEntry();
    zos.close();
}

// LAUNCHER

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    final String[] rutaFichero = {
            "src/ficheros/a.txt",
            "src/ficheros/b.txt",
            "src/ficheros/c.txt",
            "src/ficheros/d.txt"
    };

    Comprimir.ficheros(rutaFichero,"src/ficheros/fiches.zip");

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto pasa porque esta linea le pasas el `Path` completo del fichero, por lo que lo interpreta como tal:

```
byte[] readAllBytesOfFile = Files.readAllBytes(new File(ficheros[i]).toPath());
```

Si al crear el fichero separas entre el directorio y el nombre del fichero con el constructor `File(String parent, String child)` la `ZipEntry` reconocerá solamente el fichero, no la ruta completa.

```
String folder = "src/ficheros/";
String file = "a.txt";
byte[] readAllBytesOfFile = Files.readAllBytes(new File(folder, file).toPath());
```

---

Resuelto el problema, hay que ver como enfocar la solución:

- Si, como en el ejemplo, todos los ficheros van a estar en el mismo directorio, la opción es cambiar la firma del método pasándole directorio y nombres de fichero:

  ```
  public static void ficheros(
                     final String directorio, 
                     final String[] ficheros, 
                     final String nombreZip) throws IOException {
  ```
- Si, por el contrario, quieres permitir que comprima ficheros de múltiples directorios, deberás encontrar el ultimo separador en el `String` para adquirir el nombre del fichero y directorio por separado. Esto funciona con tu ejemplo:

  ```
  String folder = ficheros[i].substring(0, ficheros[i].lastIndexOf("/"));
  String file = ficheros[i].substring(ficheros[i].lastIndexOf("/")+1);
  ```

---

**NOTA:** para hacerlo redondo, te recomiendo usar `File.separator` en vez de `"/"`, con lo que haras tu aplicación transversal para [casi] todos los sistemas operativos.

```
String folder = ficheros[i].substring(0, ficheros[i].lastIndexOf(File.separator));
String file = ficheros[i].substring(ficheros[i].lastIndexOf(File.separator)+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adicionalmente comentarles,

```
ze = new ZipEntry(ficheros[i]);
```

este código debe ser reemplazado por:

```
ze = new ZipEntry("solo el nombre del archivo")
ze = new ZipEntry("archivo.txt")
```